# Number shows as number in list but is nan?

Tags: python, dataframe, complex-numbers

I wrote a program to find the (complex) roots of a function (z^3 = 1). It seemed to be working well, I got all the right roots (-0.5+0.866j, -0.5-0.866j, 1) But when I made a dataframe from it to make it into a basin of attraction (scatterplot) I missed one root.

I used the unique() function and saw that -0.5-0.866j was gone and now there's a nan+0.j.

I was wondering how this happened and how to fix it.

Thanks in advance

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

def f(x):
    return x**3 - 1

def df(x):
    return 3*x**2

n = 250
epsilon = 10**-5

rvalues = np.linspace(-2.5, 2.5, n+1)
ivalues = np.linspace(-2.5, 2.5, n+1)


roots = []
guesses = []

for r in rvalues:
    for i in ivalues:
        guess = r + i*1j
        guesses.append(guess)
        while abs(f(guess)) > epsilon:
            guess = guess - f(guess)/df(guess)
        roots.append(guess)

for i in range(len(guesses)):
    guesses[i] = round(guesses[i].real,3) + round(guesses[i].imag, 3)*1j
                
for i in range(len(roots)):
    roots[i] = round(roots[i].real,3) + round(roots[i].imag, 3)*1j




xcor = []
ycor = []

for i in range(len(guesses)):
    xcor.append(guesses[i].real)



for i in range(len(guesses)):
    ycor.append(guesses[i].imag)


df = pd.DataFrame({'xcor': xcor, 'ycor': ycor, 'root': roots})
print(df)

print(df.root.unique())
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. We don't provide debugging services. The following references give advice on debugging your code. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/six-debugging-techniques-for-python-programmers-cb25a4baaf4b)  or [Ultimate Guide to Python Debugging](https://towardsdatascience.com/ultimate-guide-to-python-debugging-854dea731e1b)